# Distance Travelled by a Projectile

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification, hyperbolic-functions, arc-length

I wanted to come up with a formula for the total distance travelled by a projectile with some initial velocity $\langle v_x,v_y\rangle$ in $\mathbb R^2$.

Its parametrization should be the following:

$$v(t)=\left\langle v_xt,\frac{1}{2}gt^2+v_y\right\rangle$$

Its component derivatives are as follows:

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=v_x$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=gt+v_y$$

The arclength $\ell$ of a parametrized curve is given by

$$\ell = \int\limits_a^b\sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2}\;dt$$

To find the total distance travelled between times $t=0$ and $t=T$, we have the following:

$$\ell=\int\limits_0^T\sqrt{v_x^2+(gt+v_y)^2}\;dt$$

Now for a $u$-substitution:

$$u=gt+v_y$$
$$du=g\;dt$$
$$(0,T)\mapsto (v_y,gT+v_y)$$

$$\ell=\frac{1}{g}\int\limits_{v_y}^{gT+v_y}\sqrt{u^2+v_x^2}\;du$$

Now for a hyperbolic substitution:

$$u=v_x\sinh(\theta)$$
$$du=v_x\cosh(\theta)\;d\theta$$
$$(v_y,gT+v_y)\mapsto(a_0,a_T)$$

We declare the following constants:

$$a_0=\text{asinh}\left(\frac{v_y}{v_x}\right)$$
$$a_T=\text{asinh}\left(\frac{gT+v_y}{v_x}\right)$$

Our integral becomes the following:

$$\ell=\frac{1}{g}\int\limits_{a_0}^{a_T}\sqrt{v_x^2\sinh^2(\theta)+v_x^2}\cdot v_x\cosh(\theta)\;d\theta$$

Recall $\sinh^2(\theta)+1=\cosh^2(\theta)$.

$$\ell=\frac{v_x^2}{g}\int_{a_0}^{a_T}\cosh^2(\theta)\;d\theta$$

Recall $\cosh^2\theta=\frac{1+\cosh(2\theta)}{\theta}$.

$$\ell=\frac{v_x^2}{2g}\int_{a_0}^{a_T} 1+\cosh(2\theta)\;d\theta$$

Integrating:

$$\ell=\frac{v_x^2}{2g}\left(\theta+\frac{\sinh(2\theta)}{2}\right)_{a_0}^{a_T}$$

Recall $\sinh(2\theta)=2\sinh(\theta)\cosh(\theta)$.

$$\ell=\frac{v_x^2}{2g}\left(a_T-a_0+\left.\sinh(\theta)\cosh(\theta)\right|_{a_0}^{a_T}\right)$$

Recall $\cosh(\theta)=\sqrt{1+\sinh^2(\theta)}$.

$$\ell=\frac{v_x^2}{2g}\left(a_T-a_0+\left.\sinh(\theta)\sqrt{1+\sinh^2(\theta)}\right|_{a_0}^{a_T}\right)$$

Back-substituting $a_0$ and $a_T$:

$$\tiny{\ell=\frac{v_x^2}{2g}\left(\text{asinh}\left(\frac{gT+v_y}{v_x}\right)-\text{asinh}\left(\frac{v_y}{v_x}\right)+\sinh\left(\text{asinh}\left(\frac{gT+v_y}{v_x}\right)\right)\sqrt{1+\sinh^2\left(\text{asinh}\left(\frac{gT+v_y}{v_x}\right)\right)}-\sinh\left(\text{asinh}\left(\frac{v_y}{v_x}\right)\right)\sqrt{1+\sinh^2\left(\text{asinh}\left(\frac{v_y}{v_x}\right)\right)}\right)}$$

Simplifying:

$$\scriptsize{\ell=\frac{v_x^2}{2g}\left(\text{asinh}\left(\frac{gT+v_y}{v_x}\right)-\text{asinh}\left(\frac{v_y}{v_x}\right)+\frac{gT+v_y}{v_x}\sqrt{1+\frac{(gT+v_y)^2}{v_x^2}}-\frac{v_y}{v_x}\sqrt{1+\frac{v_y^2}{v_x^2}}\right)}$$

---

I felt like using a hyperbolic trig sub as opposed to a regular trig sub would make integration easier as it allowed me to avoid integrating secant cubed by parts. But I'm not sure if I got all the details right with regard to changing the limits of integration and wanted to know if this formula would work. Thank you.

Comment: $1+\sinh^2 \theta= \cosh^2 \theta$ so you can make a simplification, before last line

Comment: I intentionally rewrote $\cosh(\theta)$ that way for composition of inverses